# How to fix object image not loading properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, class, pygame

I'm writing a code where several enemies can spawn on the screen.
The enemy attribute used to take a color attribute that was used for all of the enemies, and I am now trying to change it to an image that I can load.
I am also interested in doing this so that I can get_rect() from the image that I will use for checking when the enemies are at a certain position on the screen.

The problem is that as I tried to replace the color attribute with an image attribute, the previous code was so dependent on loading up the enemies with the color attribute that I'm having a hard time getting the code to work.
With the current code I've written, it doesn't load the image properly.

This is the old (functional, using the color attribute) that I started with:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


class Enemy:

    def __init__(self, pos, color):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(pos, (26, 45))
        self.color = color
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self, player):
        vel = (player.center - self.pos).normalize() * 4
        self.pos += vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    bg_color = pg.Color('gray12')
    player_color = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
    enemy_color = pg.Color('sienna1')
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    player = pg.Rect((100, 300), (26, 50))
    enemy_list = [Enemy((100, 300), enemy_color)]

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    enemy_list.append(Enemy((400, 0), enemy_color))

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            player.x -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            player.x += 5
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            player.y -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            player.y += 5

        for enemy in enemy_list:
            enemy.update(player)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player)
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            enemy.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

And the following is the code that I have tried to change, but as of now can't get to work:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
import os
from os import path

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "images")

enemy_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, "goblin.png"))

class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, image):
      pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image = pg.transform.scale(enemy_img, (48,37))
      self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self, player):
        vel = [-5,0]
        self.pos += vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(Enemy.image, Enemy.rect)


def main():
    bg_color = pg.Color('gray12')
    player_color = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    player = pg.Rect((100, 300), (26, 50))
    enemy_list = [Enemy((100, 300), enemy_img)]

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    enemy_list.append(Enemy((400, 0), enemy_img))

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            player.x -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            player.x += 5
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            player.y -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            player.y += 5

        for enemy in enemy_list:
            enemy.update(player)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        #pg.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player)
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            enemy.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Could someone please help me figure out what went wrong and what code I'm supposed to alter or add? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problen is this line:

```
screen.blit(Enemy.image, Enemy.rect)
```

Here you're trying to access the `image` **class attribute** of `Enemy`, but the `Enemy` class does not have such an attribute, and also no `rect` attribute.

You could fix this by using

```
screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

which will use the **instance attributes**.

But since you already use the `Sprite` class, don't bother with drawing the sprites to the screen yourself and use a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
import os
from os import path

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "images")

enemy_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, "goblin.png"))

class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, image):
      pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image = pg.transform.scale(enemy_img, (48,37))
      self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self, player):
        vel = [-5,0]
        self.pos += vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

def main():
    bg_color = pg.Color('gray12')
    player_color = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    player = pg.Rect((100, 300), (26, 50))
    enemy_list = pg.sprite.Group([Enemy((100, 300), enemy_img)])

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    enemy_list.append(Enemy((400, 0), enemy_img))

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            player.x -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            player.x += 5
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            player.y -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            player.y += 5

        enemy_list.update(player)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        enemy_list.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```